# Adding a custom rectangle to a custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have a custom RelativeLayout, where i want to dynamically create Rectangles.

They arent shown in my current code, but i dont know whats the reason.

Custom RelativeLayout:

```
public class DrawView extends RelativeLayout {

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        this.addView(new Rectangle(this.getContext()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);   

    }
```

Custom Rectangle:

```
public class Rectangle extends View {

    public Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Rectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Rectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { 
        super(context, attrs, defStyle); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(), paint);

    }

}
```

EDIT:
Solution was:

```
public class Rectangle extends View {

    public Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Rectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Rectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { 
        super(context, attrs, defStyle); 
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = 150;
        int height = 50;

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="5sp"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="315"
        android:startColor="#FFFF6666"
        android:endColor="#FFFF1111"
        android:type="linear"
        />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing to set your Shape's `LayoutParams`. Try tho create a `Rectangle` object, set its width + height and then add it to your `RelativeLayout` :D