# Custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity where i create a new Custom RelativeLayout with this:

```
DrawView relativeLayout = new DrawView(this);
setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

In the constructor of this relativeLayout i want to add some custom Rectangle Views to it..
With this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(context, "hey", 50, 10);
        this.addView(rect);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(context, "hey2", 60, 70);
        this.addView(rect2);
```

But both Rectangles are not shown.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure since you I'm not sure how you have implemented your custom `DrawView` and `Rectangle` classes, but this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624258/adding-a-custom-rectangle-to-a-custom-relativelayout) might help!